# '(a-b-c)' to '(a-b) and (b-c)' in data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, sequence, visualization

I have a data.frame of this form:

```
  sequence support
1      a-b     0.6
2      b-c     0.6
3      a-c     0.6
4    a-b-c     1.0
5      a-d     0.6
```

and I can transform this to the following:

```
  1    2    3 support
1 a    b <NA>     0.6
2 b    c <NA>     0.6
3 a    c <NA>     1.0
4 a    b    c     0.6
5 a    d <NA>     1.0
```

I need to transform above table to like this:

```
  1    2  support
1 a    b      0.6
2 b    c      0.6
3 a    d      1.0
```

More specifically, I want to draw a Sankey Diagram.

So I have to transform the first data.table to the form of 'start node' and 'end node'.

For example, to draw the sequences 'a-b-c' and 'a-d', I need following data.frame:

```
start end
    a   b
    b   c
    a   d
```

How can I do this?

Comment: It is not clear about the expected output.  For the first output, `library(splitstackshape);cSplit(df, "sequence", "-")`

Comment: I transformed the first data.table to the second one in the question. What I expected is the third data.table in the question. Thanks again, @akrun.

Comment: Why is `a c` row not in the output?

Comment: @akrun because in the example of "a-b-c", a is not connected to c. So the output should be "ab", "bc".

Answer (score 3):

Using strsplit and apply:

```
# data
df1 <- read.table(text = "sequence support
1      a-b     0.6
2      b-c     0.6
3      a-c     0.6
4    a-b-c     1.0
5      a-d     0.6", header = TRUE, as.is = TRUE)

# result - input for sankey
datSankey <-
  do.call(rbind,
          apply(df1, 1, function(i){
            x <- unlist(strsplit(i[1], "-"))
            cbind.data.frame(
              From = x[1:length(x) - 1],
              To = x[2:(length(x))],
              Weight = as.numeric(i[2]),
              deparse.level = 0)
          })
  )

#             From To Weight
# 1              a  b    0.6
# 2              b  c    0.6
# 3              a  c    0.6
# 4.sequence1    a  b    1.0
# 4.sequence2    b  c    1.0
# 5              a  d    0.6

# plot
library(googleVis)
plot(gvisSankey(datSankey,
                from = "From", to = "To", weight = "Weight"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

We can try

```
library(splitstackshape)
i1 <- grepl("-[^-]+-", df$sequence)
df$sequence[i1] <- sub("-[^-]+", "", df$sequence[i1])
res <- cSplit(df[!(duplicated(df$sequence)|duplicated(df$sequence, 
               fromLast=TRUE)),], "sequence", "-")
res[, 2:3, with = FALSE]
#   sequence_1 sequence_2
#1:          a          b
#2:          b          c
#3:          a          d
```